# Javascript pagination (next project / previous project) with jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, pagination, portfolio, jquery-pagination

I recently came upon a [***site***](http://work.lp-sf.com/1.php) that has done exactly what I want as far as pagination goes. I have the same basic setup as the site I just found.

I would like to have prev and next links to navigate through my portfolio. Each project would be in a separate file (1.php, 2.php, 3.php, etc.) For example, if I am on the 1.php page and I click "next project" it will take me to 2.php.

The site I am referencing to accomplishes this with javascript. I don't think it's jQuery:

```
function nextPg(step) {
  var str = window.location.href;
  if(pNum = str.match(/(\d+)\.php/i)){
    pNum = pNum[1] * 1 + step+'';
    if ((pNum<1) || (pNum > 20)) { pNum = 1; }
    pNum = "".substr(0, 4-pNum.length)+pNum;
  window.location = str.replace(/\d+\.php/i, pNum+'.php'); 
}
}
```

And then the HTML:

`<a href="javascript:nextPg(+1)" class="nextProject">Next Project</a>`

I can't really decipher the code above, but I assume the script detects what page you are on and the injects a number into the next page link that is one higher than the current page.

***I suppose I could copy this code but it seems like it's not the best solution. Is there a way to do this with php(for people with javascript turned off)? And if not, can this script be converted for use with jQuery?***

Also, if it can be done with php, can it be done without dirty URLs?
For example, `http://www.example.com/index.php?next=31`

I would like to retain link-ability.

I have searched on stackoverflow on this topic. There are many questions about pagination within a page, but none about navigating to another page that I could find.

Comment: In regards to dirty URLs, could you give an example of what you would like the URL to look like if it wasn't /index.php?next=31?

Comment: It can be done with clean URLs - `example.com/page/31` for example. Usually this is set up using mod_rewrite, often in an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question you know how many pages there are going to be.  From this I mean that the content for the pages themselves are hardcoded, and not dynamically loaded from a database.

If this is the approach you're going to take you can take the same course in your javascript: set an array up with the filenames that you will be requesting, and then attach event handlers to your prev/next buttons to cycle through the array.  You will also need to keep track of the 'current' page, and check that incrementing/decrementing the current page will not take you out of the bounds of your page array.

My solution below does the loading of the next page via AJAX, and does not change the actual location of the browser.  This seems like a better approach to me, but your situation may be different.  If so, you can just replace the related AJAX calls with `window.location = pages[curPage]` statements.

**jQuery:** (untested)

```
$(function() {
    var pages = [
        '1.php',
        '2.php',
        '3.php'
    ];
    var curPage = 0;

    $('.next').bind('click', function() {
        curPage++;
        if(curPage > pages.length)
            curPage = 0;
        $.ajax({
            url: pages[curPage],
            success: function(html) {
                $('#pageContentContainer').html(html);
            }
        });
    });

    $('.prev').bind('click', function() {
        curPage--;
        if(curPage < 0)
            curPage = (pages.length -1);
        $.ajax({
            url: pages[curPage],
            success: function(html) {
                $('#pageContentContainer').html(html);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "pageContentContainer">
    This is the default content to display upon page load.
</div>
<a class = "prev">Previous</a>
<a class = "next">Next</a>
```

To migrate this solution to one that does not have the pages themselves hardcoded but instead loaded from an external database, you could simply write a PHP script that outputs a JSON encoded array of the pages, and then call that script via AJAX and parse the JSON to replace the pages array above.

```
var pages = [];
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/pages.php',
    success: function(json) {
        pages = JSON.parse(json);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your answer. I think [http://test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/ajax_test/index.php](I got it running). When this navigates, the URL stays the same (index.php) and doesn't change to 1.php, 2.php, 3.php. Is there a way for it to navigate to those pages so that the URL would change from `/index.php` to `/1.php` then from `/1.php` to `/2.php` ?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of loading the content via AJAX, replace those AJAX calls with `window.location = pages[curPage];`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without ever effecting the structure of the URL.

**Create a function too control the page flow, with an ajax call**

```
function changePage(page){
  $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myPaginationFile.php',
    data: 'page='+page,
    success: function(data){
      //work with the returned data.
    }
  });  
}
```

*This function MUST be created as a Global function.*

**Now we call the function on page load so we always land at the first page initially.**

```
changePage('1');
```

Then we need to create a Pagination File to handle our requests, and output what we need.

```
<?php
  //include whatever you need here. We'll use MySQL for this example



  $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
  if($page){ 
    $q = $("SELECT * FROM my_table");

    $cur_page = $page; // what page are we on

    $per_page = 15; //how many results do we want to show per page?

    $results = mysql_query($q) or die("MySQL Error:" .mysql_error()); //query 

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); // how many rows are returned

    $prev_page = $page-1 // previous page is this page, minus 1 page.
    $next_page = $page+1 //next page is this page, plus 1 page.

    $page_start = (($per_page * $page)-$per_page); //where does our page index start
    if($num_rows<=$per_page){
      $num_pages = 1;
      //we checked to see if the rows we received were less than 15. 
      //if true, then we only have 1 page.
    }else if(($num_rows % $per_page)==0){
      $num_pages = ($num_rows/$per_page);
    }else{
      $num_pages = ($num_rows/$per_page)+1;
      $num_pages = (int)$num_pages;
    } 

    $q. = "order by myColumn ASC LIMIT $page_start, $per_page";
    //add our pagination, order by our column, sort it by ascending 

    $result = mysql_query($q) or die ("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
      echo $row[0].','.$row[1].','.$row[2];
      if($prev_page){
        echo '<a href="#" id="prev-'.$prev_page.'"> Previous </a>';
        for(i=1;$i<=$num_pages;$i++){
          if($1 != $page){
            echo "<a href=\"JavaScript:changePage('".$i."');\";> ".$i."</a>";
          }else{
            echo '<a class="current_page"><b>'.$i.'</a>';
          }
        }
        if($page != $num_pages){
          echo "<a class='next_link' href='#' id='next-".$next_page."'> Next </a>';
        }
      }
    }          
  }
```

I choose to explicitly define the next and previous functions; so here we go with jQuery!

```
$(".prev_link").live('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();//not modifying URL's here.
  var page = $(this).attr("id");
  var page = page.replace(/prev-/g, '');
  changePage(page);              
});

$(".next_link").live('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); // not modifying URL's here
 var page = $(this).attr("id");
 var page = page.replace(/next-/g, '');
 changePage(page);
});
```

Then finally, we go back to our changePage function that we built initially and we set a target for our data to go to, preferably a DIV already existing within the DOM.

```
...
success: function(data){
  $("#paginationDiv").html(data);
}
```

I hope this gives you at least some insight into how I'd perform pagination with ajax and php without modifying the URL bar.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! that helps a lot. Although, I will need the URL change. I used the answer above by @watcher and it has worked.